# Service broker with SqlNotificationRequest

Tags: triggers, notifications, service-broker

I am in the process of evaluating a Service Broker with SQL noticiation for my project. My requirements is User places a order from System A and it will update Order Table. As soon as order is place i need to notify the System B. I have done a quick POC with Trigger , Service Broker and SQLNotificaiton ADO.NET. It is working as i expected.

What i would like to know the group 
A) What are the best practices i need to follow for this?
B) What are disadvantages with the above approach if any?
C) Are there any disadvantes of using the Triggers? If so what are those for above approach?

The order table will get order from System A like 1000 to 1500 every day. I also would like to know the performance of above approach.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is simply push data from System A to System B, then as long as there are no clients connected to System B, you won't need Sql Notification.
Instead of using triggers you may consider [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx). Take a look at ["Real Time Data Integration..."](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/07/09/real-time-data-integration-with-service-broker-and-other-sql-techniques.aspx) article on Service Broker Team Blog.

Comment: System B will process the request to down stream system. More over i need a solution which will work in both 2005 n 2008

Comment: If you decide to go the "Real Time Data Integration" way, you may have any business logic you want invoked by Service Broker activation when change notifications arrive at System B.